# Discord.py Connect call failed ('::1', 9000), [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 9000)

Tags: python, networking, discord.py

I am unable to connect to discord and am receiving this error when running the quickstart code on the discord.py official documentation. I am using the proper token as given by discord.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(token)
```

I am receiving `OSError: Multiple exceptions: [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('::1', 9000), [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 9000)`

```
Full error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Madhav\Desktop\PythonStuff\discordbot\botcode\bin\messagecontainer.py", line 5, in <module>
    import discord
  File "C:\Users\Madhav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "C:\Users\Madhav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 33, in <module>
    import aiohttp
  File "C:\Users\Madhav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\aiohttp\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import BaseConnector as BaseConnector
  File "C:\Users\Madhav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . import hdrs, http, payload
  File "C:\Users\Madhav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\aiohttp\http.py", line 1, in <module>
    import http.server
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\http\server.py", line 100, in <module>
    import socketserver
  File "C:\Users\Madhav\Desktop\PythonStuff\discordbot\botcode\bin\socketserver.py", line 13, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(sendinstruction())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Madhav\Desktop\PythonStuff\discordbot\botcode\bin\socketserver.py", line 8, in sendinstruction
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
  File "C:\Users\Madhav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\websockets\client.py", line 517, in __aenter__
    return await self
  File "C:\Users\Madhav\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\websockets\client.py", line 535, in __await_impl__
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 787, in create_connection
    ', '.join(str(exc) for exc in exceptions)))
OSError: Multiple exceptions: [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('::1', 9000), [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 9000)
```

Comment: Is your computer configured to use a proxy server? Seems like that could be what it's trying to talk to.

Comment: Not as far as I know, however I did use the first example at https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html with the port 9000 after which I started getting these errors. Is it possible that somehow that could be the issue? I restarted my computer and the problem persists though.

Comment: Seems like something got configured on your system w/ websockets that's making new connections get sent to the (no longer running) websocket server running locally. Unfortunately I don't know much about that so I can't really help, sorry! Good luck

Comment: Seems like it however I'll just mention that running "netsh interface portproxy show all" returned nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason my file was broken was because I had 2 other python scripts in the folder called socketserver.py and socketclient.py which possibly had the same name as some of the import discord.py uses. Renaming them solved the issue.